# Search response order

Tags: marklogic

In the json documents we loaded, we would like the search result document ordering to be search term found in the title property comes first, specialKeywords property second, keywords property third and shortDescription property fourth and rest of the fields in the document. we are using default scoring method and created Field word query with higher weightage to those fields, it works in most cases, but in few cases the default scoring method dominates weightage with term frequency. In my use case score simple also won't work. what would be the possible fix

Comment: Can you elaborate what code or api you are using?

Comment: Using customized xquery endpoint

Comment: this is the final query  cts:and-query((cts:directory-query("/test/HE/", "1"), cts:or-query(cts:field-word-query("learnFieldConfig", ("England", "England", "the English", "British"), ("case-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","whitespace-insensitive","stemmed","lang=en"), 1), ())), ())

Comment: It would be really helpful if you please copy the JSON sample doc with all the elements you have mentioned in your questions.